# How to delete .htaccess file recursive based on size or content

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am seeking a terminal command to recursively go through folder structures and either delete `.htaccess` files with permission of 0444 and/or if possible to match the first line in the file for a safety measure.

Had a few accounts compromised on a server, which cleared up the malware / rootkits but noticed it added `.htaccess` files inside every folder with the following content:

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|phtml|php|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Did you get hacked and backdoored in a wordpress installation by any chance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `find` to go recursively through multiple directories, search for files and execute a command like `rm` on the result.

```
find . -type f -perm 0444 -name ".htaccess" -exec echo rm {} \;
```

- `.` current diretory / can be other path e.g. `/etc`
- `-type f` search for files
- `-perm 0444` permission 0444
- `-name ".htaccess"` will only look for files named `.htaccess`
- `-exec CMD {} \;` run command like `rm` on the result `{}`
- verify output of `find` and remove `echo` to remove files

Comment: Thanks mate, before i run that... will that run through all child dirs finding .htaccess files with that perm of 0444.... seems they are within every dir so need to find and remove. just wanted to confirm before i run that command but many thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, `find` will run through every child-directory. Notice the `echo` after `-exec` will print the results containing the path.

Comment: ok cool thanks, will run that then! thanks for the help and will make answer for sure! thanks again!

Comment: oh just one thing, anyway to make "find . -type f -perm 0444 -exec echo rm {} \;" target just .htaccess files ?

Comment: By adding `-name` flag. I've updated the answer to search for files named `.htaccess`

Comment: seems some im finding are 644, anyway to add a option to that command to check file size as FTP shows them as same file size 99bytes - or if not over complicated check and match first line of source in the htaccess file but think size should do it.

Answer (score 7):

This command removes all the `.htaccess` files in all the sub folders:

```
find . -name ".htaccess" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Please do not roll back edits which objectively improve your post, in this case by adding [formatting](/help/formatting).